# Loading Compact Framework assembly with dependencies gives ReflectionTypeLoadException when run from LabView

Tags: c#

I hope this question is not too specific and someone out there can help me...

Some words for introduction:
We have a tool at work that enables us to "remote control" our embedded devices running Windows CE 6.0. The tool consists of a DLL and a EXE containing the GUI, both of them using .NET 4.0. The DLL contains the main logic and is not only used with the mentioned "remote control" tool but also with a website for device software updates. As a third use for the DLL we now want to use it with our automated test stations, that are programmed with LabView 2013.
Our "remote" application on Windows CE uses .NET CF 3.5 SP1.

The DLL works as follows: After connecting to the device the device specific main executable (netcf) is downloaded and loaded into the current AppDomain of the DLL by AppDomain.CurrentAppDomain.Load(byte[]). Afterwards, all dependencies of the device main executable are evaluated (Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()) and downloaded from the device also (AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event is used).
Now all properties of the main device executable are read via Reflection and shown in the remote tool (using a PropertyGrid).

This works in the tool and on the website.

Now the problem: when using the DLL from within LabView, it does not work. 
To be more specific: downloading assemblies from device and loading them into DLLs current AppDomain works fine, but the downloaded assemblies somehow cannot resolve their dependencies, even though they are loaded and present in the AppDomain!

Example:

Device.exe uses Device1.dll and Device2.dll (both .NET Compact Framework).
Tool.dll contains main logic, Tool.exe uses Tool.dll (both .NET 4.0).

Tool.exe starts -> Tool.dll connects to Device.exe -> downloads Device.exe -> loads Device.exe to AppDomain of Tool.exe/Tool.dll -> checks dependencies of Device.exe -> downloads Device1.dll -> loads Device1.dll to AppDomain of Tool.exe/Tool.dll -> downloads Device2.dll -> loads Device2.dll to AppDomain of Tool.exe/Tool.dll. 
=> Tool.exe shows all properties of Device.exe/MainClass in PropertyGrid (it can resolve all types used in Device.exe since Device.exe's dependencies are loaded).

Now the same with LabView:
LabViewTool.exe starts -> Tool.dll connects to Device.exe -> downloads Device.exe -> loads Device.exe to AppDomain of LabViewTool.exe/Tool.dll -> checks dependencies of Device.exe -> downloads Device1.dll -> loads Device1.dll to AppDomain of LabViewTool.exe/Tool.dll -> downloads Device2.dll -> loads Device2.dll to AppDomain of LabViewTool.exe/Tool.dll.
=> LabViewTool.exe wants to load properties of Device.exe/MainClass but fails to do so with a ReflectionTypeLoadException. LoaderExceptions state that dependency Device1.dll and Device2.dll were not found.

Does anybody have an idea on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Assembly.LoadFrom()` inside your app to add your Dlls. If you place them in the same directory, the application should pick them up without having to reference them manually.

Windows CE as a platform has some problems with DLL crunching. Small libraries might fail to load. Therefore using `Assembly.LoadFrom` might be necessary to be able to load the Assembly.